# ValidationError: Cast to [undefined] failed

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have two mongoose models `Game` and `Card` which I want to connect. I followed [this youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FVn_wj1jLN0) and I'm able to CRUD `games`, but when I want to add a Card into the cards array, i get the following error:

```
ValidationError: game validation failed: cards: Cast to [undefined] failed for value "[{"_id":"5a65b32e8f4af32fb8626db3","game":"5a651a319aa3c22d6c9ebeb7","__v":0}]" at path "cards"
    at new ValidationError (/mnt/c/Users/Martin/Documents/Web/card-creator/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validation.js:27:11)
    at model.Document.invalidate (/mnt/c/Users/Martin/Documents/Web/card-creator/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1656:32)
    at _init (/mnt/c/Users/Martin/Documents/Web/card-creator/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:418:18)
    at init (/mnt/c/Users/Martin/Documents/Web/card-creator/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:386:5)
    at model.Document.$__init (/mnt/c/Users/Martin/Documents/Web/card-creator/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:356:3)
    at model.syncWrapper [as $__init] (/mnt/c/Users/Martin/Documents/Web/card-creator/node_modules/kareem/index.js:234:23)
    at model.Document.init (/mnt/c/Users/Martin/Documents/Web/card-creator/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:324:8)
    at completeOne (/mnt/c/Users/Martin/Documents/Web/card-creator/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1988:12)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/Users/Martin/Documents/Web/card-creator/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1508:11)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/Users/Martin/Documents/Web/card-creator/node_modules/mquery/lib/utils.js:119:16)
    at runCallback (timers.js:756:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:717:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:697:5)
```

Also, there is a second error appearing from time to time when I try to post a new card to a game using postman POST Body/raw/JSON(application/JSON):

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at model.Document.toJSON (/mnt/c/Users/Martin/Documents/Web/card-creator/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:2356:37)
    at clone (/mnt/c/Users/Martin/Documents/Web/card-creator/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:164:18)
    at cloneArray (/mnt/c/Users/Martin/Documents/Web/card-creator/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:260:14)
    at clone (/mnt/c/Users/Martin/Documents/Web/card-creator/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:159:12)
    at cloneObject (/mnt/c/Users/Martin/Documents/Web/card-creator/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:246:11)
    at clone (/mnt/c/Users/Martin/Documents/Web/card-creator/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:172:16)
    at model.Document.$toObject (/mnt/c/Users/Martin/Documents/Web/card-creator/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:2065:13)
    at model.Document.toJSON (/mnt/c/Users/Martin/Documents/Web/card-creator/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:2357:15)
    at clone (/mnt/c/Users/Martin/Documents/Web/card-creator/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:164:18)
    at cloneObject (/mnt/c/Users/Martin/Documents/Web/card-creator/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:246:11)
    at clone (/mnt/c/Users/Martin/Documents/Web/card-creator/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:172:16)
    at model.Document.$toObject (/mnt/c/Users/Martin/Documents/Web/card-creator/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:2065:13)
    at model.Document.toJSON (/mnt/c/Users/Martin/Documents/Web/card-creator/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:2357:15)
    at clone (/mnt/c/Users/Martin/Documents/Web/card-creator/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:164:18)
    at cloneArray (/mnt/c/Users/Martin/Documents/Web/card-creator/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:260:14)
    at clone (/mnt/c/Users/Martin/Documents/Web/card-creator/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:159:12)
```

I noticed, that there are other people with this error, but to my knowledge, there was a misconfigured model but I couldn't find an error here.

- Node: 9.4.0
- Mongoose: 5.0.1
- MongoDB: 3.6.2

**server/models/cardModel.js**

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const cardSchema = new Schema({
    description: String,
    flavor: String,
    game: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Game'
    }
});

const Card = mongoose.model('Card', cardSchema);
module.exports = Card;
```

**server/models/gameModel.js**

```js
const Card = require('../models/cardModel');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const gameSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    description : String,
    cards: [
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Card'
        }
    ]
});

const Game = mongoose.model('Game', gameSchema);
module.exports = Game;
```

**server/routes/games.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
// const router = express.Router();
const router = require('express-promise-router')();
const Card = require('../models/cardModel');
const Game = require('../models/gameModel');

router.route('/:gameId/cards')
  .post(async (req, res, next) => {
    var { gameId } = req.params;
    var newCard = new Card(req.body);
    console.log('newCard', newCard);
    var game = await Game.findById(gameId);
    // Assign card to game
    newCard.game = game;
    await newCard.save();
    // Add card to game's card array
    game.cards.push(newCard);
    await game.save();
    res.status(201).json(newCard);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error in the post function for `/:gameId/cards`: The newCard was pushed to the array but since this was an async function the saving still had to wait (`await`) for this to happen.

**Wrong:**

```
...
await newCard.save();
game.cards.push(newCard);
await game.save()
res.status(201).json(newCard);
```

**Right:**

```
...
await newCard.save();
await game.cards.push(newCard);
await game.save()
res.status(201).json(newCard);
```

Comment: you are totally wrong bro...
console.log(typeof game.cards.push(newCard)) // prints 'number'